# How to detect an account is a contract account or not

Tags: smart-contract

I want to exclude all contract account to use my contract. How can I detect the account has deployed contract or not?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible at the moment. The best you can do is have an oracle that keeps track of this information and query a table from the oracle, however this isn't guaranteed to work as oracle's can break or go offline and in general are 'centralised solutions'.

Answer (score 1):

This is no contract account like ETH, there are only accounts who deployed contracts, so you can't judge wether an account is so called contract account or not just by name.

You can use

> cleos get code **accountname**

and check the code hash result

```
cleos get code notacontract
code hash: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

cleos get code eosio
code hash: 66444bcdb50a89cec3e028e94d9d096bee050377048ba48cd6bea172ecdf6f85
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools such as EOSpark which provide all the details of an EOS account including deployed contract details. You simply enter the account name on the website/portal. It provides information including EOS balance, how custom tokens & airdrops, transaction details (including any deployed contracts), staking/unstaking, ect.